# Xtend/Xpand find and replace (rule)

Tags: java, loops, xtext, xtend, xpand

Is it possible set a rule that will allow an Xpand method to output a specified string of text depending on the input. For example:

```
«FOR a:e.attributes»
 Type = «a.eClass.name»
 Value = «a.name.toFirstUpper»

«ENDFOR»
```

The above code may output:

```
Type = StringAttribute
Value = String1

Type = IntegerAttribute
Value = 123
```

How would I make this output:

```
Type = String
Value = String1

Type = int
Value = 123
```

I know this can be done with if statements but I would like to be able it to be more or less automatic. It would be a waste to have to specify such rules every time I need to output these details in the same file. Could someone show me what kind of code I could use to achieve this? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest that you create a reusable [Xtend](http://help.eclipse.org/galileo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.xpand.doc/help/ch01s05.html) helper

```
toSimpleName(String inp):
    switch (inp) {
        case "StringAttribute"  : "String"
        case "IntegerAttribute" : "int"
        // ...more cases here...
        default                 : inp
    }
;
```

and then call it from your Xpand template like this:

```
«FOR a:e.attributes»
 Type = «a.eClass.name.toSimpleName()»
 Value = «a.name.toFirstUpper»

«ENDFOR»
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Not as difficult as I expected. Although I had to change the code a little to make it valid in Xtend:


`def toJavaType(String inp){
  switch (inp) {
   case "NumberAttribute" : "String"
   case "StringAttribute" : "int"
   default : ""
  }
 }`